# How to create and access a multi level map in Velocity?

Tags: apache, velocity

I want to create a dynamic map with multiple values for each entry, and then be able to run over that  map and match up values with another list. Here is what I mean:

```
#set($map = {})

#foreach( $Item in $someQuery.getResults() )

  #set( $day = "Monday") ## This would be a dynamic value.. just example here

  #set( $startTimeHour = "8")
  #set( $startTimeMinute = "00")

  #set( $endTimeHour = "17")
  #set( $endTimeMinute = "30")

  ## Now I need here to put this into a map...
  $!map.put("${foreach.count}", "dayValue": $day, "startTimeHourValue": $startTimeHour, "startTimeMinuteValue": $startTimeMinute, "endTimeHourValue": $endTimeHour, "endTimeMinuteValue": $endTimeMinute)

#end

With this, I want to be able to do this in another for each loop

#foreach($newItem in $someList)

    #if($newItem.DayValue IS IN MAP DAY VALUE $map.dayValue????)
        ## Print everything associated with this map entry
            $map.dayValue
            $map.startTimeHourValue
            $map.startTimeMinuteValue
            $map.endTimeHourValue
            $map.endTimeMinuteValue
    #end

#end
```

I am very new to velocity and have no Java knowledge, so any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!